# Can't resolve Java Eclipse import

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I've been trying to import third-party source code into my Eclipse project. I just can't figure out why my java file can't reference these classes. I've imported the files into my project, included the library in the build path, and verified that I am using the correct package name. Nonetheless, every time I try to use one of these classes, I get `<classname> cannot be resolved to a type`.

In the screenshot below, you can see in red where each class reference fails. I think that my import statements are correct (lines 1-4), so I just don't see why this isn't working. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

[image]

Here is what I've done regarding the build path. If I try to add anything to the Source, the source code I've included crashes immediately.

[image]

Another approach, based on @Guido suggestion below, is to handle this through the Source tab. However, as soon as I do this, every file in my third-party code crashes with some combination of either `The declared package "com.flickr4java.flickr" does not match the expected package` or `The import com.flickr4java cannot be resolved`:

[image]
As example of one of the classes, the first error occurs on `FlickrException`. Here is the third-party code for that class:

```
package com.flickr4java.flickr;

/**
 * Exception which wraps a Flickr error.
 * 
 * @author Anthony Eden
 */
public class FlickrException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7958091410349084831L;

    private String errorCode;

    private String errorMessage;

    public FlickrException(String errorMessage) {

        super(errorMessage);
    }

    public FlickrException(String errorMessage, Throwable rootCause) {

        super(errorMessage, rootCause);
    }

    public FlickrException(Throwable rootCause) {

        super(rootCause);
    }

    public FlickrException(String errorCode, String errorMessage) {
        super(errorCode + ": " + errorMessage);
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

}
```

Comment: what Java version are you using ?

Comment: You imported sources files: if you want to build (and use) those files, you have to set the directory as a source directory ( right click on project.- configure build path)

Comment: Or alternatively, put the binary (.class files) jar in a lib directory (configure build path again, third tab)

Comment: @guido - can you explain this a little more please? I've tried various different things with the build path. Nothing works. I've edited my OP to show my current build settings. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @usr55410 a sources directory (containing .java classes) should be in the first tab in build path configuration `source`. This will mean you build the library sources along your code. Another way is using compiled classes (.class files) in a jar, this would be configured under `libraries` tab

Comment: Thanks again. I've tried that, but it blows everything up. I made another edit to my post to show what I did and the errors (hundreds of them) that result. Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @usr55410 this is basic eclipse project layout configuration; refer to the documentation fpr the possible options, sections about "java build path" .

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen before in Eclispe. Most of the times it goes away if you click on your project and in the menu go to `"Project" -> "Clean"`

Here is the link of the things you can try to resolve this. I have found [this post](http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=207) useful

Comment: I've tried to clean the project many times. This doesn't solve anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Under the project menu is the "Build Automatically" option checked

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug with the IDE. Cleaning it multiple times aren't helping, so I just removed that project from workspace and re-imported. That worked.